# Protect files from download if not authenticated

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I've an old Sitefinity 4.1 project that has almost 4 years of data inserted daily.
I've been asked to do some management on this and one of the steps I've to performs is to avoid a user can download a file if he's not authenticated.
Right now if I point to the file path it prompts me to download. Since the backend is quite slow , is there a way I can set this via API?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you can achieve this using the Fluent API, more info: http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-modify-permissions-of-dynamic-content-items-using-the-fluent-api. Needless to say, if you want to avoid the quite slow backend you definitely need to upgrade to latest version of the CMS.

Hope this helps!